# Python search engine going online

Tags: javascript, python

I have written a local search engine in Python, which I feel was a good idea. It requires constant little changes and Python appears to be always readable when I go back. And it is good with regular expressions too. But now the engine is in demand online. Should I stick with python? Is there a good module/library (I know urllib superficially, but I mean something more specialized) for wrapping a local search engine (as simple as a method taking the string/query) with a method that can communicate with Javascript and keep/sort/order the incoming queries?

Comment: Watch the google IO video on how they made youtube. It had a lot of prototyping done with python. They optimized some of the bottle necks but managed to stick with a lot of python code. (of course this is mainly for the backend). If you're using something like google app engine you don't have to worry about this. most of the time will be in remote procedure calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like Python, I would use Django or even Ruby on Rails. Both are great MVC (Model, View, Controller) frameworks which have manageable learning curves. I suggest Ruby on Rails because I was able to transition into it from Python and I really enjoyed its conventions and ease of use. Check them out.